# Creating a login with AWS cognito and javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, cookies, authentication, amazon-cognito

I am creating a login page. The idea is to take the username and password then use that to get an id token from AWS cognito user pool.

Then I need to store the token in a database and transfer that token to index.html along with the username. This is because index.html needs the token to make a post request to an API gateway using the same id token and it needs to know the user name to keep track of which user is currently logged in.

Now the index.html has to check if the token transferred to it matches the token in the database or not.

If it does and the token is not expired, then there is no redirection, otherwise, the index.html redirects to login.html.

The problem is my back-end completely relies on Amazon Lambda functions and API gateways because my company does not want me to use any back-end language. Now, I found that lambda functions could not set browser cookies nor read browser cookies.

This left me no choice but to use javascript cookies, sessions and local storage to transfer the token and username to index.html. However, this approach is considered to be insecure.

There aren't any tutorials on a secure login system using cognito.

Note: Any other secure login system will do the work, but remember I need to pass username and password to user pool to get an ID token which means, if I use any other login method, then I would now need to pass username and password both to index so that index can make a request to user pool to get an id token and make a request to the API gateway.

Now my question is, is there a way to actually transfer data to index from login without compromising security? Can I use lambdas in any other way to transfer the tokens?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "However, this approach is considered to be insecure" citation needed. By whom? Doing it in what way? Because tokens are used for that exact reason: allowing authentication without disclosing credentials.

Comment: Sorry, I meant using javascript cookies was considered to be insecure, not tokens.

Comment: @ Federico klez Culloca : I just wan't to know if there is a way to transfer HTTP only cookies to index.html. Or if there is an entirely different way in which I could transfer tokens and username to index without compromising security. Because I cannot use PHP or node, I can only use javascript and AWS lambdas.

Comment: Also, I would like to mention that cognito does have a provision of setting cookies. The code is in github : https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js, use case no: 26 . I have tried that, but it  resulted in an error : AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CookieStorage is not a constructor. I googled the error but could not find the result, so if anyone could help me with this as well.

Comment: I couldn't get `CookieStorage` to resolve through `CognitoIdentityServiceProvider` either, but you can do `import { CookieStorage } from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';` and use it directly (`new CookieStorage()`), or do `import * as Cognito from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';` and use it like `new Cognito.CookieStorage()`.  You won't be able to create `HttpOnly` cookies with it, though.

Comment: Oh..that's too bad..because this entire problem came up because I wanted to create HTTP only cookies. Otherwise I was already using document.cookie in javascript. But thank you for atleast letting me know that I could not create HTTP only cookies using cognito's cookie method. You saved me alot of time.

Answer (score 2):

> Now, I found that lambda functions could not set browser cookies nor read browser cookies.

I don't think this is strictly true.

Using [Lambda Proxy Integration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html) gives your Lambda function visibility into and control over many aspects of the HTTP request.  This includes setting and reading arbitrary headers (including `set-cookie`).

To demonstrate, you can set a function like this up and attach an API Gateway trigger (with Lambda Proxy Integration enabled) to it:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var returnobj = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json", "access-control-allow-origin": "*", 
            "Set-Cookie": "testcook=testval; path=/; domain=xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com; secure; HttpOnly"
        }, 
        "body": JSON.stringify({})
    };
    console.log("headers", event.headers.Cookie);
    callback(null, returnobj);
};
```

This function returns a `Set-Cookie` header that the browser will respect and send along with future requests to this domain.   If you hit this in a browser twice, you'll see the cookie sent by the browser and logged by the lambda on the second request.

[image: DevTools image showing HttpOnly and Secure]

If you aren't willing to use Lambda Proxy Integration, you  can probably still pull this off by [mapping part of your Lambda response to a header](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html) in API Gateway.

Comment: Thank you @Mike Patrick . I will definitely try this out. My first approach WAS to use lambda functions. So yes, I will definitely use this method. Also,  I am asking this in advance because I didn't find a proper answer to this question. Can a lambda function also read these cookies after setting them? Because that would definietly solve my problem. Once again, thank you so very much.

Comment: @Namah yes, it can.  All the cookies sent to the Lambda are in the `Cookie` header, which is available via `event.headers.Cookie`.  Your lambda will have to parse apart the contents of this header.  In my example, the header will contain `testcook=testval`.